# How do you prioritize which element on the screen has priority for scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css

There are some strange things happening when I try and have multiple scrollbars in one scope.  Let me clarify that in my code, id of pageContainer is synonymous with "scrollfield", and id of contentWrap is synonymous with "subscrollfield" in my explanation below.

Let me also clarify that there are two issues:

- the first is with the functionality of scrolling.  Firefox is the only browser that encounters this issue, and I describe it in its respective section.  It is only testable in Firefox.
- the second is with how I would like to add a custom property to scrolling.  This is currently testable in Chrome, and after I get the first issue with Firefox working, it will be testable in Firefox as well.

**ISSUE ONE** (FOR FIREFOX ON PC):

--When you scroll in a scrollfield within a scrollfield (a subscrollfield), you must move the mouse first in order for the client to know that you intend to scroll in the subscrollfield; otherwise, it will assume that, despite how your mouse is hovering over the subscrollfield, you intend to scroll in the primary scrollfield.  In other words, I would like whichever scrollfield you are hovering over to be the one that scrolls.

--TO TEST: scroll all the way to the bottom of the code snippet, then scroll all the way to the top.  **Do so without moving your mouse after positioning it in the beginning!**  This will reveal the issue–that the subscrollfield is not scrolling, even when the mouse hovers over its div.

Once Firefox's issue is fixed, it will have the issue that Chrome encounters:

**ISSUE TWO** (FOR CHROME ON PC OR EITHER BROWSER ON MAC):

--When you scroll in a scrollfield within a scrollfield (a subscrollfield), it works as intended, but I would like to make it such that if you are at the footer and are hovering over the subscrollfield, you scroll up from the footer, then scroll up in the subfield, then scroll up in the main field.  In other words, I would not like the footer to stay at the bottom of the page if your cursor is over the subscrollfield when you scroll back up.

--TO TEST: scroll to the bottom of the scroll snippet while keeping your cursor in the middle of the screen, then scroll back up; you will see that the subscrollfield scrolls up first (keeping the footer at the bottom), and then the scrollfield scrolls up.  How do I make the opposite happen?

Here is the pseudocode for my website:

```css
body {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#pageContainer {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.snapPoint {
  position: relative;
  scroll-snap-align: start none;
}

#prelude {
 height: 100vh;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #000020;
   }

#header {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 9.75vh;
  z-index: 3;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #167988 0%, #1590A3 20%, #1DB3CA 100%);
  overflow: hidden;
}

#contentWrap {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  font-size: 4vw;
  padding: 5vh 0 0;
  height: 85.25vh;
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(#C3C3C3 0%, #F4F4F4 12vh, #F4F4F4 calc(100% - 15vh), #C3C3C3 100%);
}

#footer {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #167988 0%, #1590A3 20%, #1DB3CA 100%);
  height: 10vw;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: 3;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="pageContainer"><!--THIS CONTAINS THE MAIN SCROLL SCOPE (WITH SNAP)-->
    <div id="prelude" class="snapPoint"><h1 style = "color: #F4F4F4;">PRELUDE</h1></div>
    <div id="header" class="snapPoint"></div>
    <div id="contentWrap"><!--THIS CONTAINS THE SUB-SCROLL SCOPE-->
      <p>Test One<br/><br/><br/>Test Two<br/><br/><br/>Test Three<br/><br/><br/>Test Four</p>
    </div>
    <div id="footer" class="snapPoint"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

How should I approach this issue?  Can I write JavaScript that fixes the issue, or is there some technique with CSS I am not considering?

Comment: Can you plz share your CSS.

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal I shared my CSS!

Comment: If I hover over the SCROLLBAR (either one) and use my mouse scroll wheel it scrolls that one.  Please update your question to be very specific about your desired behavior given that seems to be properly scrolling (at least to me).  The scroll snap does make it act somewhat non-standard to my expectation but that is more my expectation than your desired behavior and either might be "more right"

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Even after keeping your mouse entirely still, it moves the subscrollfield if you scroll down then up?  It does not do this for me.  Regardless, I'll update my question.

Comment: Yes, that "snap" part you have does make it act odd but that is not really the question.  BTW I am using Chrome browser

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I just tried with the Chrome browser, and it worked differently.  This is good to know, as I am using Firefox.  On Chrome, would it be possible to fix the oddness–i.e., how the subfield scrolls up before scrolling up first on the superfield if the mouse is hovering over both?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, try add `overscroll-behavior: none` on the contentWrap div.